# Elastic Search dynamic field stored as both analyzed and not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to index json documents in elasticsearch. I don't have schema of the document, its dynamic.

I need to store the fields as both analyzed and not analyzed. Also I need it to be dynamic.

1. Can we use dynamic templates to achieve this ?
2. Also is it possible to keep the field names same for both analyzed and not analyzed ?
3. Do I need to do any special handling while searching those fields ?

Answer (score 0):

You will accomplish this by using dynamic templates yes, by creating a dynamic mapping for the fields (or the pattern of fields, e.g all strings) like this:

```
"dynamic_templates":[
        {
            "template_myStringFields":{
                "match":"somepattern",
                "mapping":{
                    "type":"multi_field",
                    "fields":{
                        "{name}":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                        },
                        "_tokenized":{
                            "type":"string",
                            "index":"analyzed",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }...
```

Then, to search in both analyzed and not-analyzed, you could use "pattern match" if you dont like to search in both fields at once, or search the "_all" field if ok with match in any field. The field name is the same, but with a postfix, like myField._tokenized in the above example.

Comment: I think I need to add match_mapping_type : string, if I want to restrict it to string.